# How to solve "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:" while working with Google spreadsheet api?

Tags: java, guava, google-sheets-api

I am working on reading Google spreadsheet data on a button click. But I am stuck with this problem:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.stringIsNullOrEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
at com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Strings.java:69)
at com.google.api.client.util.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Strings.java:34)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow.loadCredential(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:249)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:113)
```

I have tried adding **guava dependencies 27.1-jre**, but it also not working. The code is working fine when I run the main method inside the class. But when I tried to call the method of this class in another class, it is throwing the exception.

What should I do?

These are the dependencies I have added:

```
"com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client-extensions" % "1.6.0-beta" ,
"com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-sheets" % "v4-rev1-1.21.0"  ,
"com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client-java6" % "1.30.7" ,
"com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-jetty" % "1.30.5",
```

Comment: You obviously have a dependency conflict in your project. You'll need to add a dependency insight log or your POM/build.gradle/whatever-else-build-tool file

Comment: I am using SBT built

Comment: Are you running it as the unnamed module? Are you importing other libraries in the other class, that you're not importing when you're running it in your main method inside the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There is a object discrepency in your code due to the use of the `google-collections` library. Remove this to resolve the conflict.*